# Angular.js constants issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, constants

I'm slightly confused, I'm following this tutorial to try and get autheictaion to work. https://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/

I'm stuck on the first stage

This is my app.js

```
// create main module, adding dependencies for ionic, angular router, angular  mock and apps own modules

var jailbreak = angular.module('jailbreak', ['ionic', 'ui.router', 'map', 'chat', 'constant'])

jailbreak.run(function(AUTH_EVENTS) {
  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(AUTH_EVENTS);
})
```

Then this is my constants.js

```
angular
  .module('constant', [])
  .constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {
    notAuthenticated: 'auth-not-authenticated',
    notAuthorized: 'auth-not-authorized'
  })
  .constant('USER_ROLES', {
    admin: 'admin_role',
    public: 'public_role'
  });
```

Comment: And what the error are you getting?

Comment: When I'm trying to show AUTH_EVENTS its empty null

Answer (score 1):

It might be that syntax error where you've got a semicolon after your module declaration, but then you try to chain `.constant` onto it.

Change this:

```
var constants = angular.module('constant', []);
```

into this:

```
var constants = angular.module('constant', [])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, still getting after your recommendation. Very confused because i'm linking my constants correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

When angular tries to bootstrap your main module, others should be available:
(just a note, avoid global variables, use getters to access modules)

```js
angular
  .module('constant', [])
  .constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {
    notAuthenticated: 'auth-not-authenticated',
    notAuthorized: 'auth-not-authorized'
  })
  .constant('USER_ROLES', {
    admin: 'admin_role',
    public: 'public_role'
  });


angular
  .module('jailbreak', [
    /** 'ionic', 'ui.router', 'map', 'chat', **/ 'constant' /**, 'ngMockE2E' **/
  ])
  .run(function(AUTH_EVENTS) {
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(AUTH_EVENTS);
  });
```

```css
#debug {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, .3);
  font-family: monospace;
  word-wrap: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="jailbreak"></section>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response appreciate it. The problem is I need to user var jailbreak in order for the rest of the app to function. I'm not getting any data from AUTH_EVENTS any suggestions please ? Updated code